# numpy.dot(a, b) gives wrong result on multiplication of matrices with similar dimenstions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Let matrices a, b be [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] i.e of (1 x 4) dimension. 
On applying numpy.dot(a, b) the result is 30 instead of raising exception that both the matrices shapes are not aligned. 
How can a (m x n) matrix be multiplied with (m x n) matrix? Does numpy automatically transposes one matrix to align their shapes and then multiply?

Comment: The [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is not the same thing as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Check the shape attributes of `a` and `b`, it's likely that they are one dimensional (`(4,)` instead of `(1,4)`). In this case, ``dot`` computes the dot product between two vectors, giving a scalar output 30.

Comment: [Working as intended](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: problem solved, started learning numpy and confused python lists with numpy arrays. working as intended with numpy arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [59]: a = b = np.matrix([1,2,3,4])

In [60]: np.dot(a.T, b)      # 1
Out[60]: 
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
        [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
        [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])

In [63]: np.dot(a, b.T)      # 2
Out[63]: matrix([[30]])

In [64]: np.dot(a, b)        # 3
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

More generally, if `X` has shape `(m, n)` and `Y` has shape `(n, p)`, then `np.dot(X,Y)`
returns an array of shape `(m, p)` and which is the result of matrix
multiplication.

1. Since `a.T` has shape `(4, 1)`, and `b` has shape `(1, 4)`, the result of matrix multiplication is an array of shape `(4, 4)`.
2. Since `a` has shape `(1, 4)`, and `b.T` has shape `(4, 1)`, the result of matrix multiplication is an array of shape `(1, 1)`.
3. `np.dot(a, b)` raises a ValueError since arrays of shape `(1, 4)` and `(1, 4)` can not be matrix multiplied. NumPy never transposes axes automatically.

Comment: Just started learning numpy, and got confused with python lists and numpy arrays, both are way different. Working as intended with numpy arrays.